# Subgroups of the group $G_2 \times G_2$

Tags: lie-groups

Does the group $G_2 \times G_2$ have the group $SO(7)$ (or its double cover $Spin(7)$) as its subgroup? Here, $G_2$ is the compact exceptional group $G_2$.

Comment: Elementary questions such as this one belong on MathStackExchange, not here.

Comment: A product of groups $H_1\times H_2$ contains a simple group $S$ iff either either $H_1$ or $H_2$ contains $S$. Idem for Lie algebras.

Comment: @YCor, Thanks for the answer. Would you please introduce me a reference for this statement and its proof?

Comment: Consider the projection map $p_1$ onto the first factor. Either the map is an isomorphism restricted to $S$ (in which case $S$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H_1$) or it has a kernel. $S$ is simple, so the kernel must be all of $S.$ In which case, $S$ is contained in $H_2.$

Comment: @IgorRivin , Thanks. I see, very nice proof.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answered in the comments.

Comment: This is a valid question - many questions have fairly complete answers in comments.

Answer (score 1):

A product of groups $H_1\times H_2$ contains a simple group $S$ iff either either $H_1$ or $H_2$ contains $S$. Idem for Lie algebras. -- [YCor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299731/subgroups-of-the-group-g-2-times-g-2#comment2639263_1299731)

Consider the projection map $p_1$ onto the first factor. Either the map is an isomorphism restricted to $S$ (in which case $S$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H_1$) or it has a kernel. $S$ is simple, so the kernel must be all of $S.$ In which case, $S$ is contained in $H_2.$ -- [Igor Rivin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299731/subgroups-of-the-group-g-2-times-g-2#comment2639265_1299731)